# EPplus 7 and need to filter and existing pivottable

Tags: excel, filter, pivot, epplus

I have an existing Excel XLSM file with 10 internal sheets. One of it named "basedata" has only data in it. Columns are: year(2022, 2023, 2024), article, ordervalue. A second sheet named "overview" is the pivot based on the data of "basedata". The pivot has rows with "article", columns with "year" and the data is the sum of counts of "ordervalue".

In excel itself or C# and with interop library its no problem to filter the pivottable so, that I only see the year "2024".
In the lib of epplus and internet I only find examples and helps to "ADD" pivot and "ADD" filters. But I want to filter the existing pivot in my sheet, i want to reference to the existing column "year" and hide or unhide the items, so after saving it and and other user opens it he can see data in the pivot only of the year "2024".

I tried the lib "openxml", but same problem.